# How do I get UEFI to automatically boot the Linux Boot Manager (managed by systemd-boot) instead of the OS Boot Manager, of Windows 10?

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, uefi, systemd-boot

I would like to set my laptop with UEFI firmware and a Windows 10 / Arch Linux dual boot to use the Linux Boot Manager (managed by `systemd-boot`) by default on startup, instead of the OS Boot Manager (which boots Windows 10 only). In my own attempts to fix this problem, I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> on startup and pressed <kbd>F10</kbd> to enter "BIOS Setup". Then I went to the "Boot" tab and found that my options for what device I boot from were:

- USB (UEFI)
- USB
- OS Boot Manager

My default setting at the moment is USB (UEFI), as it makes booting from a live USB more convenient as this is not too uncommon for me to do.

As you can see there is no "Linux Boot Manager" option. I can access the Linux Boot Manager, option by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> (which gives me my boot options) after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> on boot, so I know it is there. It works too, I am presently running Arch Linux, which I booted via this method. This question, however, is me asking whether I can get my laptop to automatically boot the Linux Boot Manager instead of the OS Boot Manager, when no live USB is available to boot from.

Per Libre Arch's answer I ran:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 2 -l /EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi -L "Linux Boot Manager"
```

after disabling both Safe Mode and Secure Boot in UEFI and this returned:

```
** Warning ** : Boot0005 has same label Linux Boot Manager
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0006,3006,0001,0005,0008,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* grub
Boot0002* Notebook Hard Drive
Boot0004* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot0005* Linux Boot Manager
Boot0006* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0007* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot0008* rEFInd Boot Manager
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3006* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot0000* Linux Boot Manager
```

yet still whenever I reboot my Windows Boot Manager (i.e., OS Boot Manager) is being used by default. `/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi` does exist on `/dev/sda2`.

Comment: Does /EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi  exist?

Comment: Sure does, I even just edited this question to include that fact. I was going to share its contents until I realized that `.efi` files are not text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probably installed Windows 10 *after* Arch Linux and Windows wiped out the systemd-boot UEFI entry. You need to re-enable systemd-boot to have the menu you want. Make sure that you have Secure Boot and Fast Startup disabled in the UEFI/BIOS settings and follow the instructions written [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot#Menu_does_not_appear_after_Windows_upgrade) on the Arch Wiki.

You might also be able to use the GRUB repair tool to install GRUB (instead of systemd-boot) via a live USB.

Comment: I tried the suggestions in your first paragraph and they failed, that is, still the Windows OS Boot Manager is being used by default. I went into my BIOS setup menu (by pressing `F10`), so I can change the boot preferences, and no Linux Boot Manager option appears in this menu, so I can't fix this issue. GRUB is proving too much of a pain for me to be willing to try it again, at least not until this OS Boot Manager issue is fixed. The precise command I ran based on your ArchWiki Link was `efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 2 -l /EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi -L "Linux Boot Manager"`

Comment: @BrentonHorne Did you follow the instructions written under the heading "Menu does not appear after Windows upgrade" in the Arch Wiki link that I mentioned?

Comment: Nope, didn't seem relevant since I haven't done a Windows 10 update since installing Arch Linux.

Comment: @BrentonHorne Which OS did you install first? Arch or Windows?

Comment: Windows 8 came pre-installed on this PC, then I upgraded to Windows 10 and then I installed Arch Linux.

Comment: @BrentonHorne What is the output of `$ lsblk -f`?

Comment: Nvm, I managed to solve the problem by running `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi` in an admin prompt on Win 10. Thanks.

Comment: @BrentonHorne You're Welcome :)